# Executing stored procedure with multiple parameters in Python using different parameter sets

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I need to execute a stored procedure having 2 date parameters from Python. I want to change parameters and execute procedure multiple times in a loop using parameters set which are in a dataframe rows. My code is as below;

```
def _get_dataset(date_param1, data_param2):
    sql="exec [dbo].[SP_Name] (%s,%s)" % (date_param1, 
    date_param2)
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL 
    Server};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;DATABASE=db;UID=userid;PWD=password')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    data = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)
    return data 

for i in range(len(dataframe)):
    first_date = df.iloc[i][0]
    second_date = df.iloc[i][1]
    _get_dataset(str(first), str(second))
```

The error I am getting;

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'exec [dbo].[SP_name] (2019-06-25,2019-06-24)': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '2019'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

What is wrong in the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actual query that you try to execute?

Comment: Try single quotes around the dates on the `sql` string: `"exec [dbo].[SP_Name] ('%s', '%s')"` - I don't have a MS SQLServer around for testing.

Comment: @LajosArpad  The actual query is supposed to be like 'exec SP_name '2019-06-24' '2019-06-25'''.

Comment: @PauloScardine It didn't work

Comment: If you execute that directly in SQL Server, without Python, is it working?

Comment: Yes it is working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an SQL Server around for testing, but it is better to pass the parameters using `read_sql` as it will use the underlying database driver to perform the string interpolation in a safe way:

```
def _get_dataset(date_param1, data_param2):
    sql = "exec [dbo].[SP_Name] (?, ?)" 
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
       'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xxx.xxx.xx.xx;DATABASE=db;UID=userid;PWD=password'
    )
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    data = pd.read_sql(sql, cnxn, params=(date_param1, data_param2))
    return data
```

You can also use an ORM like SQLAlchemy to [pass parameters in a driver-neutral way, so your code is not tied to a specific driver syntax](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#advanced-sqlalchemy-queries):

```
In [559]: import sqlalchemy as sa

In [560]: pd.read_sql(sa.text('SELECT * FROM data where Col_1=:col1'), 
   .....:             engine, params={'col1': 'X'})
   .....: 
Out[560]: 
   index  id                        Date Col_1  Col_2  Col_3
   0      0  26  2010-10-18 00:00:00.000000     X   27.5      1
```

Comment: I didn't work. This time I get error as below;                                       
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'exec [dbo].[SP_Name] (?, ?)': ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Check your database driver documentation for which of the five syntax styles, described in PEP 249’s paramstyle, is supported. I'm not sure it is `?` or `%(name)s` for SQL Server. Also, I don't know what type the parameters are - if they are dates, you may want to convert them to a string in a format you are sure SQL Server will understand.

Comment: Wanna [zoom](https://us04web.zoom.us/j/901173652)? I have a few minutes to help you before my first commitments today.

Comment: Thanks @PauloScardine, but now I am not able to do zoom.

Comment: Check my update about using SQLAlchemy to iron out differences between database drivers. @GulsahAyhan

Comment: ( cc: @GulsahAyhan ) - T-SQL `EXEC` does not use round brackets. You could use `sql = "EXEC [dbo].[paulo_sp] ?, ?"` or `sql = "{CALL [dbo].[paulo_sp] (?, ?)}"`

Comment: @GulsahAyhan - [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56770251/edit) to provide a [mcve] including the definition of the stored procedure and the *exact* Python code you are using to call it.